# How to find the inverse of an expotential

Tags: exponential-function

Please tell me how to find the solution for this.

$$y= 3 + x + e^{x}$$

The range or the domain is not given. I'm just asked to find the inverse function of this.

Comment: Perhaps you should begin by showing us what you have tried to do.

Comment: And the context of the problem. It looks like part of a bigger problem where there is likely a much better approach than your first instinct on how to attack it.

Comment: @Toiya: I am pretty sure there is no closed formula for the inverse function using elementary functions.  Who asked you this?

Comment: do you want inverse itself or just some info about it like number of roots , solution with other functions etc. I agree with @StefanSmith

Comment: @Toiya  : see the answer below, but note that to know that the range is $\mathbb{R}$ you need not just that $y' > 0$ but $y' > 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $y'=1+e^{x}>0$, then $y$ is monotonically increasing on all of $\mathbb{R}$. That's why they don't state a domain and range-because the inverse function is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$. As others have alluded to, there isn't a solution in terms of elementary functions. However, the following Mathematica commands get the inverse function in terms of the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function):
\begin{align*}
&f[x\_]:=3+x+\mathrm{Exp}[x]; \\
&\mathrm{InverseFunction}[f]
\end{align*}
returns $f^{-1}(x) = -3-W(\exp(x-3))+x$. (Mathematica calls the W function "$\rm{ProductLog}$") I'm a bit surprised that any homework problem would require you to pull out the Lambert W function. In any case, you can use the fact that $z=W(z)e^{W(z)}$ to verify that this is indeed the inverse function.

I have no clue how one would have gotten this result without a computer algebra system.